# Browser issue with constant refresh when typing in text field

Tags: browser

This is more of a computer question than a programming question and it I am posting in the wrong place, please let me know.  My system is running Windows 8, 64bit.  Regardless of which browser I use - IE or Chrome, every time I attempt to type something into a text field, the screen refreshes.  I have also noticed that the refresh symbol starts to flash.  I can get that to stop by pressing the ESC key, but then the screen goes blank.  I have done a complete scan of my computer and found no viruses.  Any ideas would be great appreciated as this is making things very difficult, including typing this message.

Comment: Its not a keyboard issue as I have connected a different one and still happens.

Comment: the only other suggestion I have  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/typing-causes-ie8-to-refresh/1cc1803a-68fa-408f-881d-56df2411c010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled and that seemed to fix the problem.